# Compute mean of a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, mean

I have a `3D numpy array` (called data) of shape `(600L, 24L, 351L)`.
The first dimension `(600)` represents the `number of epochs`.
The second dimension `(24)` represents the `number of channels`.

The last dimension represents voltage values over a period of time of `351 ms` (one voltage value per millisecond).

For each of the 24 channels and 351 time steps, I would like to average voltage values over the 600 epochs.

I would thus get a numpy array of shape (24, 351).
I guess I need to write something like:

`mean_data = np.mean(data, axis = (some sort of tuple))`,

but I can't figure out the tuple needed for the axis argument. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `mean_data = np.mean(data, axis=0)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, indeed you are correct, sir, my apologies, thanks for correcting me! 